# v1 Function SDK references Newtonsoft.Json v9.0.1 while function references project that needs v10

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Picture of dependencies with latest function sdk

[image: Picture of dependencies with latest function sdk]

The project that the function references includes this binding redirect in its config.

```
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
```

Building shows warning that there are conflicting versions of Newtonsoft.Json and with verbosity, build output shows that version 9.0.1 was chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version difference won't cause problem unless runtime needs to populate `Newtonsoft.Json` objects. See [this explanation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk#faq).

> If you don't require Newtonsoft.Json objects to be fulfilled by the runtime, then you can specify the version you like to use in your own functions in your csproj

It's simple to check, if you don't meet any version conflict problem when debugging project, it means your code works fine with v10 Json.Net, then you could just ignore the harmless warning.

Comment: I get a runtime error when I debug from the code that the azure function references. FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @SimonSchlegel Have you installed v10 Newtonsoft.Json in function project?

Comment: Actually adding the binding redirect in the Functions csproj worked. Thanks!